# Mysql: Get Strings?

Tags: java, mysql

I try to receive all names out of my database.

I did write this code:

```
  public static String getCmdCommand(int resultCount) throws Exception {
        try {
          // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          // Setup the connection with the DB
          connect = DriverManager.getConnection(""+MyBot.mysqlDbPath+"",""+MyBot.mysqlDbUsername+"",""+MyBot.mysqlDbPassword+"");
          PreparedStatement zpst=null;
          ResultSet zrs=null;
          zpst=connect.prepareStatement("SELECT `befehlsname` FROM `eigenebenutzerbefehle`");
          zrs=zpst.executeQuery();
          if(zrs.next()){
             return zrs.getString(resultCount);
          }else{
              return "-none-";
          }
        }catch (Exception e) {
              throw e;
            } finally {
              close();
            }
      }
```

and i start the method by running a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= cmdAmount-1; i++){

try {
    eebBenutzerBefehl = dao.getCmdCommand(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

cmdAmount is a integer with the valuable of the total fields inside the database.

so i.e  My database holds name1 name2 name3,  is it wrong to call them like this? :

```
return zrs.getString(resultCount);
```

which should be:

```
zrs.getString(0) = name1
zrs.getString(1) = name2
zrs.getString(2) = name3
```

I always receive java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, perhaps it just continue to check the first entry only in the database :confused:

Comment: Which is the value of `resultCount`? Print it at the beginning of the method, maybe it's not the right one.

Comment: Hey, just tested. resultCount is always the right number so thats not the problem.

Comment: Off-topic: Why are you prepending and appending empty strings to your DB connection settings? That's a lot of extra String objects you are creating for no reason.

Comment: `zrs.getString(resultCount);` is getting the column value from column `resultCount`...but your query only returns a single column?

Comment: remember that it's zero based.. if you want to get the last column's string, it would be: `zrs.getString(numOfColumns-1);`

Comment: It would appear that you seem to think that `ResultSet#getString` is going to return you a row value, but it's responsible for return the value of the specified column for the current row (as dictated by `ResultSet#next`

Comment: so what is hould actually get from the db in order to match get?(0) = name1  get?(1) = name2   ...? or isnt there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

return zrs.getString(resultCount);

The getString() method should be given the index of the column you want to return which is always going to be the same. You should pass in a constant here such as 0.

Also, you should open the database only once rather than over and over again in that one method by passing in the "connect" variable as a parameter.

Here's what I would do if you are wanting to retrieve the name from each row of the table.

```
public static ArrayList<String> getCmdCommand(Connection connect) throws Exception {
    try {
        PreparedStatement zpst=null;
        ResultSet zrs=null;
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        zpst=connect.prepareStatement("SELECT `befehlsname` FROM `eigenebenutzerbefehle`");
        zrs=zpst.executeQuery();

        // The result set contains all the names retrieved from the call to the database, so
        // you just need to iterate through them all and store them in a list.
        while(zrs.next()) {
            names.add(zrs.getString(0));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        close();
    }

    return names;
}
```

You don't need to tell it how many fields there are because it will figure that out itself.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(""+MyBot.mysqlDbPath+"",""+MyBot.mysqlDbUsername+"",""+MyBot.mysqlDbPassword+"");

try {
    ArrayList<String> names = dao.getCmdCommand(connect);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if(names.size() < 1) {
  // " - none - "
}
```

Comment: resultSet is the same as i from the loop so its always +1 and the loop will run as many times there are names in it.

Comment: But doesn't the query only return a single column?

Comment: Yep, thats what it should.

Comment: I believe that is your problem. getString() needs to always be given 0 since there is only one column returned, yet resultCount is growing so you are going to get an out of bounds exception. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)

Comment: so how i can tell it to actually return name2 out of the string?

Comment: Just so I understand the problem correctly, you have a name on every row of the table that you want to retrieve, correct?

Comment: Fixed a couple of mistakes, but that should work. I haven't tested it, though.